# Could not find matching constructor even when it does

Tags: groovy, constructor

```
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.Node
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild

/**
 * Created by on 2017-03-25.
 */


File file = new File("/Users/user1/output/1")
XMLLoader xmlLoader = new XMLLoader(file);
HashMap<String, XmlSlurper> temp = xmlLoader.sendNodes()
JunitDataParser junitParser = new JunitDataParser(temp)
junitParser.populateStats()

public class XMLLoader {
    HashMap<String, XmlSlurper> rootNodes; // Collection of root nodes for Junit xml files

    public XMLLoader(File junitFile) {
        rootNodes = new ArrayList<>()
        // If file is directory then closure will search directory to find valid xml files
        if (junitFile.isDirectory()) {
            junitFile.eachFile {
                if (validateFile(it)) {
                    rootNodes.put(it.name, new XmlSlurper().parse(it)) // Load each fine into arraylist of XMLSlurpers
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (validateFile(junitFile)) {
                rootNodes.put(junitFile.name, new XmlSlurper().parse(it))
                // Load single fine into arraylist of XMLSlurpers
            }
        }
    }

    boolean validateFile(File checkFile) {
        if (checkFile.name.endsWith('.xml')) {
            assert checkFile.exists(): "The file entered could not be be read"
            assert checkFile.canRead(): "The file entered could not be be read"
            return true;
        }
        return false
    }

    HashMap<String, XmlSlurper> sendNodes() {
        return rootNodes
    }
}


public class JunitDataParser extends GeneralDataParser {


    def JunitDataParser(HashMap<String, XmlSlurper> rootNodes) {
        super(rootNodes)
    }

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<TestSuites>> getPopulatedData() {
        return super.getPopulatedData()
    }

    void populateStats() {
        ArrayList<TestSuite> stats = getTestSuites();
    }

    ArrayList<TestSuite> getTestSuites() {
        ArrayList<TestSuite> testSuites = new ArrayList<>()
        rootNodes.get("first.xml").'**'.findAll {
            (it.name().equals("testsuite")) && (it.children().getAt(0).name().equals("testcase"))
        }.each {
            TestSuite temp = new TestSuite(it.attributes().get("name"), it.attributes().get("tests").toInteger(), it.attributes().get("errors").toInteger(), it.attributes().get("time"), it.attributes().get("timestamp"), getTestCases(it))
            testSuites.add(temp)
        }
        return testSuites
    }

    ArrayList<TestCase> getTestCases(NodeChild testSuiteNode) {
        ArrayList<TestCase> testCases = new ArrayList<>()
        testSuiteNode.childNodes().each {
            String time;
            if (time!=null && time.length()>0) {
                time = it.attributes().get("time")
            } else {
                time = "Time Not Found"
            }
            testCases.add(new TestCase(it.attributes().get("name"), getOutCome(it), time))
        }
        return testCases
    }

    TestResult getOutCome(Node testCaseNode) {
        String testMessage = "hi"
        int testOutcome = 0;
        if (testCaseNode.childNodes().size() != 0) {
            testCaseNode.childNodes().each {
                it.attributes().each {
                    testMessage = testMessage + "\n $it.key : $it.value"
                }
            }
            testOutcome =1
        }
        TestResult temp = new TestResult(0,testMessage)
        return temp
    }

}

// The Base abstract class that all additional parsers should extend and populate
public abstract class GeneralDataParser {
    HashMap<String, XmlSlurper> rootNodes
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<TestSuites>> populatedData

    public GeneralDataParser(HashMap<String, XmlSlurper> rootNodes) {
        this.rootNodes = rootNodes
    }

    abstract void populateStats()

    abstract ArrayList<TestSuite> getTestSuites()

    abstract ArrayList<TestCase> getTestCases(NodeChild testSuiteNodes)

    abstract TestResult getOutCome(Node testCaseNode)

}

public class TestSuites {
    ArrayList<TestSuite> testSuites

    TestSuites(ArrayList<TestSuite> testSuites) {
        this.testSuites = testSuites
    }
}

public class TestSuite {
    String testSuiteName
    int numOfTests
    int numOfErrors
    int numOfFailures
    String timeTaken;
    String timeStamp;
    ArrayList<TestCase> testCases

    TestSuite(String testSuiteName, int numOfTests, int numOfErrors, int numOfFailures, String timeTaken, String timeStamp, ArrayList<TestCase> testCases) {
        this.testSuiteName = testSuiteName
        this.numOfTests = numOfTests
        this.numOfErrors = numOfErrors
        this.numOfFailures = numOfFailures
        this.timeTaken = timeTaken
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp
        this.testCases = testCases
    }
}

public class TestCase {
    String testCasename
    TestResult testOutcome
    String testCaseTime = ""

    TestCase(String testCasename, TestResult testOutcome, String testCaseTime) {
        this.testCasename = testCasename
        this.testOutcome = testOutcome
        this.testCaseTime = testCaseTime
    }
}

public class TestResult {
    int valOfResult
    String textOfResult

    TestResult(int valOfResult, String textOfResult) {
        this.valOfResult = valOfResult
        this.textOfResult = textOfResult
    }
}
```

I keep getting a matching constructor could not be found can anyone see any issues?

> Caught: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: TestSuite(java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList)
>   groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: TestSuite(java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList)
>       at JunitDataParser$_getTestSuites_closure2.doCall(JunitXMLToBeautifulHTML.groovy:70)
>       at JunitDataParser.getTestSuites(JunitXMLToBeautifulHTML.groovy:67)
>       at JunitDataParser.populateStats(JunitXMLToBeautifulHTML.groovy:62)
>       at JunitDataParser$populateStats.call(Unknown Source)
>       at JunitXMLToBeautifulHTML.run(JunitXMLToBeautifulHTML.groovy:13)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is correct.

The constructor's signature is:

```
TestSuite(String testSuiteName, int numOfTests, int numOfErrors, int numOfFailures, String timeTaken, String timeStamp, ArrayList<TestCase> testCases)
```

And you're trying to use:

```
new TestSuite(it.attributes().get("name"), it.attributes().get("tests").toInteger(), it.attributes().get("errors").toInteger(), it.attributes().get("time"), it.attributes().get("timestamp"), getTestCases(it))
```

So you're not passing a `numOfFailures`.

Comment: Thanks, Sometimes a second eye is all you need.
That worked !

Comment: If i move TestSuite, TestCase and TestResult into the abstract class as inner classes   on the line 

`TestResult temp = new TestResult(0,testMessage)`

it complains that

> Caught: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: GeneralDataParser$TestResult(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String)
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: GeneralDataParser$TestResult(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String) -------- Any idea why ? @doelleri